# How to deal with type mismatch- String and String?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting a type mismatch when I want to perform an assignment.
The required value is String but I have got String?. My question is: how should I deal with it, via toString method or rather by adding non-null asserted(!!) call. I'm wondering which of them is better for safety or maybe performance. The question is rather about best practices for a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using `!!` operator. It should be used when you are a hundred percent sure that there's no null. It always better to use **Elvis** operator (default value expression which is evaluated and assigned if the expression from the left-hand side is null)

```
val s1: String? = null
val s2: String = s1 ?: "default value if s1 is null"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
val someString : String = someOtherNullableString ?: ""
```

it will take the value of someOtherNullbleString if it is not null if it is  null then it will take ""

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways. It depends on the requirements

```
var str1: String? = null

//....

str1.notNull{ //no default value
    // your code
    str2 = it

}
```

or if you want to provide a value in case str1 is null

```
str2 = str1?:"default_value"
```

Answer (score -1):

I like the takeIf approach:

```
val someString = nullableString.takeIf { it != null } ?: ""
```

someString will take nullableString value unless it's null. If it's null, then it will be set to "".

I like this approach specially on Service level so the person using my service won't need treat null values ever. Obviously the logic between the {} can be far more complex than this example.

Comment: that's kind of pointless since you can just do `nullableString ?: ""`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out something that I already said in my own answer.